# NodeJS MongoDB Dynamic Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a NodeJS server running express with a get method at '/api/jobs/'. When called I get some querystring parameters from the url and they make a query against the MongoDB database to get jobs.

```
Example Url: '/api/jobs/?Groups=1,2&Statuses=3,4'
```

The MongoDB query i am trying to construct is this:

```
{ $or: [{"Group.Id" : 1}, {"Group.Id" : 2}], $or: [{"Status.Id": 3}, {"Status.Id": 4}]}
```

If I run this directly against the database I get the results I need but I can't think of way of constructing the query dynamically in JavaScript. Any attempt i've made gives me an object like this as the $or property can only exist once in a proper JSON object.

```
{$or : [{"Group.Id" : 1}, {"Group.Id" : 2}]}
```

Any ideas on how to do this either using JavaScript or thorugh the MongoDB Node API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly get the query properties, which will be strings:

```
const groupString = req.query.Groups; // === '1,2'
const statusString = req.query.Statuses; // === '3,4'
```

Split at the commas and parse as integers:

```
const groupNums = groupString.split(',').map(parseInt); // === [1, 2]
const statusNums = statusString.split(',').map(parseInt); // === [3, 4]
```

Then search for any of the group IDs. Your query should look like this:

```
const query = {"Group.Id": { $in: groupNums }, "Status.Id": { $in: statusNums } };
```

Do the same for the status IDs.

Comment: That did it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
var queryArry = [];
for (var i in req.query) {
    var sampleObject = { value: [] };
    sampleObject.name = i;
    req.query[i].split(',').forEach(function(each) {
        sampleObject.value.push(parseInt(each));
    })
    queryArry.push(sampleObject);
 }
  var mongoquery = {};

  for (var i in queryArry) {

     mongoquery[queryArry[i].name] = queryArry[i].value;

 }
  res.send(mongoquery);
 });
```

But in this case, you have to send same name field of MongoDB and query parameter key. If you did this it is fully dynamic query builder.